# How to modify RankBoost to maximize area under recall-precision curve instead of AUC?

Tags: machine-learning, roc, ranking, boosting, precision-recall

Using the WeakLearn algorithm from the [original RankBoost paper](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/jmlr/papers/volume4/freund03a/freund03a.pdf), how do you set the optimal threshold to maximize AU-RPC (instead of AUC)? And, once that threshold is set, how do you calculate the AU-RPC for use in calculating alpha?

[This paper](ftp://ftp.cs.wisc.edu/machine-learning/shavlik-group/oliphant.ilp09.pdf) suggests that the "area under the recall-precision curve [is] a much better metric [than AUC] when working with highly skewed data sets", which is my current application.  The paper proposes a modification of RankBoost.B that purports to maximize AU-RPC.  However, the authors are using learners based on first-order clauses, while I need to use the originally proposed WeakLearn learners.  How can I apply the same idea with the original learner algorithm?